# Export all assets in same artboard size png(Adobe illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a problem, How do I export all assets in the same artboard size. I mean if I use artboard 1000x1000px. how I export all assets with 1000x1000px png images.(In adobe illustrator)
Every time I export size is changed. Please help

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

In your illustrator file with the assets in separate layers, make a layer 1000x1000, save as psd. When you open the PSD file in photoshop, you can then "Export layers to files..." retaining the size of the artboard.